# WebSphere Liberty Profile connector port

Tags: websphere-liberty

Does WebSphere liberty profile 8.5.5 have RMI or SOAP port?
If so how to config with `server.xml` and connect via java client remotely.

Comment: Do you mean for JMX, or for application SOAP or RMI traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liberty supports RMI over IIOP as of version 8.5.5.6.  Information on how to configure it is available here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_config_iiopEndpoint.html

SOAP is available over HTTP/HTTPS ports and are configured using httpEndpoints.  There is a useful tutorial for configuring SOAP/HTTP and developing a client/server application that uses it here:
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/sample_ejbwebservicessample/

Hope this helps, Andy